# Gradle JUnit android run all but @FlakyTest

Tags: android, gradle, junit, android-espresso

I have a few tests that have multiple annotations:

```
@Test
@LargeTest
@FlakyTest
```

I found a way to run only @LargeTest from [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing-templates/tree/master/AndroidTestingBlueprint).

> ./gradlew app:connectedAndroidTest
>   -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.size=large

Is there a way to run all Instrumentation Tests except those annotated as @FlakyTest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    testInstrumentationRunnerArgument 'notAnnotation', 'android.test.suitebuilder.annotation.FlakyTest'
  }
}
```